# Extract html tag data from QDoc setHtml

Tags: c++, qt, web-scraping

I am making a qt application that needs to scrape some stuff off the web. I have got the html in form or QNetworkReply and written the reply into a QDoc object like so:

```
    QNetworkReply *reply(manager.get(request));
    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
    QTextDocument doc;
    doc.setHtml(reply->readAll());
```

I want to extract data from the HTML as I would in eg python. Is there a way that's possible to do it in QT C++.

Example HTML data:

```
<tr class="chainrow aright November2020">                
            <td class="acenter inthemoney">
                <a>quote</a>
            </td>
            <td class="inthemoney">84.66</td>
            <td class="inthemoney">0.00</td>
            <td class="inthemoney">0.00</td>
            <td class="inthemoney">82.75</td>
            <td class="inthemoney">83.35</td>
            <td class="inthemoney">27.00</td>
        <td class="strike-col">35.00</td>
            <td class="acenter ">
                <a>quote</a>
            </td>
            <td class="">0.02</td>
            <td class="">0.00</td>
            <td class="">0.00</td>
            <td class="">0.00</td>
            <td class="">0.01</td>
            <td class="">1.00</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Can you bring an example of HTML data you get? What exactly do you want to extract?

Comment: The HTML data is a table and I need to extract 2 values from that table.

Comment: @vahancho I have edited the question and added example HTML

Comment: You need to use an HTML parsing library to extract the data you want.